# ruby long line wrap up

Tags: ruby, coding-style

How to wrap up this long line so not break the maximum 80 length rule? At where to break the line?

```
raise XxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxError unless [HTTP_STATUS_CODE[:OK], HTTP_STATUS_CODE[:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx]].include? http_status_code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break `unless` into a multi-line block. I'll suggest that you extract the array out into a variable perhaps?

```
accepted_codes = [HTTP_STATUS_CODE[:OK], HTTP_STATUS_CODE[:created]]
unless accepted codes.include? http_status_code
  raise StandardError
end
```

Comment: to break into multi-line, put a \ at the end is suffice?

Comment: You could, but .. the whole point of a 80 column max is for better readability and IMO, its better to reduce the actual code length.